# Complicated Regular Expression

Tags: regex

Hello I am trying to figure out a regular expression for the following where the alphabet consists of 'a','b','c','d':

Any combination of 'a','b','c','d' is acceptable as long as 'd' is never followed by ('d'|'a') and 'b' is never followed by ('b'|'c'). Any help would be great! Thanks.

EDIT: The one that got me closest is (a|b?|c|d?)* but this does not account for the fact that a 'd' can not be followed by an 'a' and a 'b' can not be followed by a 'c'.

Comment: Sounds like an odd job for a Regex. Why should this be a regex? Also: What did you try or do you expect the solution from us?

Comment: Should this be a homework assignment, please declare it as such. What have you tried yet?

Comment: It looks like you should be able to do it using negative lookahead. Have you tried that?

Comment: Not a homework problem but just practice for learning complicated regex expressions. Me and a friend are sending eachother challenges and this one stumped me. I have tried a variety of things. The one that got me closest is (a|b?|c|d?)* but this does not account for the fact that a 'd' can not be followed by an 'a' and a 'b' can not be followed by a 'c'.

Comment: @Barmar This would mean something like (a|b(?!(b|c))|c|d(?!(d|a)))* yes? I am not sure if my way of adding two variables to the negative lookahead is correct ( the ?!(b|c) portion )

Comment: Yes, it's correct. See AD7six's answer for another way of writing it, but they're equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break the problem down into its component parts:

### Any combination of 'a','b','c','d' is acceptable

This would be the simple expression:

```
[abcd]
```

However, given the extra restrictions on the characters d and b this becomes:

```
[ac]
```

### d not followed by d or a

This can be achieved with a simple [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
d(?![da])
```

### b not followed by b or c

This is only slightly different than the previous character match:

```
b(?![bc])
```

### Adding it all together

The complete one-character regex therefore becomes:

```
[ac]|d(?![da])|b(?![bc])
```

Or as a full expression:

```
/^([ac]|d(?![da])|b(?![bc]))+$/
```

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding this expression will not accept the empty string whereas /^([ac]|d(?![da])|b(?![bc]))*$/ would also include an empty string? And thanks for the help!

Comment: * matches 0 or more times - so yes, `/^(whatever)*$/` will match an empty string. + matches 1 or more times - it won't match an empty string. It's probably a good idea to test things on [an online testing tool](http://regex101.com/) as it'll easily highlight such behavior for you.